# Python how best can I save combination of song names and records bought tallies to a file and read it back to update the tallies

Tags: python, file, arraylist

Im trying to keep a tally of song sales for a music chart in python. as in the following code

I want to be able to increment song sales and update the Music Charts.txt file as well as retrieve and display the current file information on screen. It tried to do this by writing the list information in musicChart and recordsBought but its not working. Any simple solution/ suggestion would be helpful

```
chartFName = "Music Charts.txt"

musicChart="Kathys Song \n Sunshine on Leith \n White Christmas\n"
recordsBought=[0,0,0]

fileChart=open(chartFName,"w+")
#fileChart.write(str(musicChart))
",".join(musicChart)
fileChart.write(str(musicChart))
fileChart.write(str(recordsBought))


'''for row in range(len(musicChart)):  # each row is a list
    fileChart.write("\n".join(musicChart[row]))
    fileChart.write("\n".join(recordsBought[row])) # separate rows on separate lines
    #print(musicChart[row][col])'''
```

Comment: `",".join(musicChart)` does not operate 'in-place' you need to assign the result to a name (eg `musicChart =",".join(musicChart)` ). However it is not doing what you think (or want). Try printing it out immediately after the assignment.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: maybe you should keep it as list or dictionary and use `json` file for this. But frankly, I would keep it as `csv` and use `panda.DataFrame` to work with this. `pandas`  can makes calculations - like `sum`, `average`, `groupby`. It allows to search in rows. And it can generate plots. So it can be useful for statistical information.